# external script in XSLT

Tags: perl, xslt

I have the below XML file and how do call the `perl` script in XSLT. Because i would like to update the id each `entry`. For example `<entry id="5">` and next entry should be `<entry id="10">` like that.

My XML is:

```
<feed>
  <author> 
    <firstName>f</firstName>
    <lastName>l</lastName>
  </author>
  <date>2011-01-02 </date>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <Name>aaa</Name>
    <Content>XXX</Content>     
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>2</id>
    <Name>bbb</Name>
    <Content>YYY</Content>   
  </entry>
</feed>
```

and my XSLT is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="updateItems" select="feed/entry" />
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="feed">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::entry)] | entry[not(id = $updateItems/id)]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateItems" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think it's possible to call a Perl script for manipulating XML data from XSLT. If you use Saxon (which I suppose you do because you use XSLT 2.0) you can somehow use Java classes.

However, if I get your requirement right, there is no need to use an external programming language. As far as I understand, you just want to change your IDs by multiplying them by 5. So, I'd suggest doing something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select=". * 5"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This script doesn't touch anything except the text value of your id - element which is multiplied by 5. That's it.

Comment: it's working fine. But how to add in the `attribute` instead of `element`? and it's not possible to call external script in `XSLT`?